# Flutter - How to create this kind of animated search bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, web-applications, flutter-animation

What I need:

[image]

Click on to the searchbar => Animated searchbar moves as shown

What I have tried:

Currently, I am using Navigator push but the effect isn't sleek as how I would want it to be. Would love to find out if it is possible to achieve the intended effect shown above and how to do it. Thanks!

In the AppBar:

```
InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
                  height: 35,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 3,
                          blurRadius: 5)
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.search, size: 25, color: Colors.grey),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Text('Search for Food, Drinks, Items',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 12))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SearchPage()),
                  );
                },
              )
```

SearchPage.dart

```
class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          // The search area here
          title: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.black),
                      onPressed: () {
                        /* Clear the search field */
                      },
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Search...',
                    border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm i think its kind similar to open container, try to look to this package named **animations: ^2.0.3** and try to read the read me and look for **Container transform** like when clicking the search bar its gonna enlarge but on a different screen

Comment: Thanks! I'll read the docs for that, let's see what I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Hero animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) to do these animations between screens. What you need to do is to wrap the Search bar on both the screens with the `Hero` widget and add a unique id to it.

It is easy to implement, just read the official flutter documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a class call [SearchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html). It's a widget that allows you to implement the search functionnality in your app with this kind of effect.

You can find how to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF1KMfQOpjM)